# paypal php sdk to setup recurring payments

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal php sdk to setup payments for recurring. But i am not able to find how to setup recurring. Normal payments are working fine.

I am using SDK from github

```
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK
```

After generating link using

```
            $payment->create($apiContext);

            $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

I am redirecting user using the link generated. After the payment is successful the user is redirected to my success url which is `success.php?processor=paypal`

Under which i get all data by using

```
$paymentId=$data['payment_id'];
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
```

I have a question here. I am getting the state as `created` and not `approved`

do i need to use

```
$execution = new PaymentExecution();
$execution->setPayerId($_GET['PayerID']);
```

after that ? or the process was complete before.

After this i need to know what to use from that SDK to make recurring payments.Its really confusing to find a good example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a plan... then agreement... then execute agreement.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Sorry for the short answer...

Comment: This short answer is better then a very long explanation. Btw i figured that out. It took 2 days but was worth of information i got to know about paypal. My code is complete now. Thanks. I am accepting the answer as correct because that is a procedure to complete this.